# Jquery object returned is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am attempting to set up an onClosed function for my fancybox (1.3.4) but running into much trouble.  The fancybox 'href': paramater is working correctly but the 'onClosed' function returns undefined.  I am very new to Jquery.  What am I Missing?

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
          'href': $(this).attr('data-href'),
          'padding' : '20px',
          'width' : 950,
          'overlayOpacity'   :  '0.4',
          'overlayColor'         :  '#000',
          'hideOnContentClick' :   false,
          'autoScale'        :   true,
          'transitionIn'         :   'fade',
          'transitionOut'    :   'fade',
          'speedIn' : '300',
          'speedOut' : '300',
          'type'             :   'iframe',
          'onClosed' : function() {
              alert ( $(this).attr('data-href') );
          } 



      });
```

For debugging purposes I have tried to use the alert function to view the output of the onClosed function.  My end goal is to change the location of the current window to a separately defined url within my ".clickable-row".

replace alert with:

```
window.location.replace( $(this).attr('data-href2') );
```

HTML

```
<tr class='clickable-row' data-href='link1.asp' data-href2='link2.asp'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple variable scope issue. The `this` inside your close event handler is not the same `this` that's in your click handler. Use a local variable in your click handler to "save" `this` and then use this variable inside the close handler.

```
(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        $.fancybox({
          'href': $(this).attr('data-href'),
          'padding' : '20px',
          'width' : 950,
          'overlayOpacity'   :  '0.4',
          'overlayColor'         :  '#000',
          'hideOnContentClick' :   false,
          'autoScale'        :   true,
          'transitionIn'         :   'fade',
          'transitionOut'    :   'fade',
          'speedIn' : '300',
          'speedOut' : '300',
          'type'             :   'iframe',
          'onClosed' : function() {
              alert (self.attr('data-href') );
          } 
      });
```

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Comment: Conventionally `self` means `this`, not `$(this)`.